# ¿Cómo posicionar imagenes en una ventana que muestra una imagen de fondo en tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x

Como puedo de poner imágenes en una ventana que muestra una imagen de fondo en la ventana, **un aspecto importante es que la ventana cambia de tamaño con la imagen lo cual me dificulta aún más insertar imágenes encima de la imagen de fondo de la ventana y que todas estas imágenes cambien de tamaño con la ventana**, `place` parece funcionar para mí, pero si quisiera usar `place_forget` no funcionaría, en cambio, si uso `grid` para colocar un widget en la ventana, aparece un cuadro blanco alrededor de este widget en la parte inferior de la ventana.

**Aquí hay un ejemplo de lo que se espera lograr:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVPG5.jpg

Hasta ahora pude redimensionar la imagen de fondo pero con las demás imagenes me es imposible, por favor si pudieran orientarme se los agradeceria un monton ya que soy nueva en esto de la programacion.**Muchas gracias**.

## Clase: para redimensionar las imagenes

```py
import os   # os.path.join(), os.listdir()
import sys  # sys.argv
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class ResizeCls(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, index, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, kwargs)
        self.image = Image.open (index)
        self.image_copy = self.image .copy()

        self.background = ImageTk.PhotoImage (self.image)

        self.img = Label (self, image= self.background)
        self.img .pack (fill= 'both', expand= True)
        self.img .bind ('<Configure>', self.resize)

    def resize(self, event):
        self.image2 = self.image_copy .resize ((self.master .winfo_width(), self.master .winfo_height()))
        
        self.background2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (self.image2)
        self.img .config (image= self.background2)
```

## Clase: que muestra las imágenes

```py
class TopCls(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, folder, path_lst=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.folder = folder
        self.path_lst = [os.path.join(self.folder, name) for name in os.listdir(self.folder) if name.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.gif'))]

        # Imagen 1:
        self.frame_image_delay_complete = ResizeCls(self, self.path_lst[0], bd=0)
        self.frame_image_delay_complete       .grid(column=0, row=0)

        # Imagen 2:
        self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial = ResizeCls(self, self.path_lst[1], bd=0)
        self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial       .grid(column=0, row=0)                             # [ NOT POSITIONED ]

        # Text: "Insertar u Ocultar Imagen"
        self.lbl_text_guia                  = Label(self, text='Insertar / Ocultar imagen', font=('Calibri',7,'bold'), bg='black' , fg='white', bd=0)  
        self.lbl_text_guia                   .place(x=2, y=48)    
        self.lbl_text_guia                    .bind('<Button-1>', self.open_image_miniature)

        # Widgets No Posicionados:  
        self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial .grid_remove()

        # Evento: Para posicionar los widgets
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.new_position_text_guia)


        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def new_position_text_guia(self, event):
        toplevel_width  = self.master.winfo_width() / 35
        toplevel_height = self.master.winfo_height() / 13
        x = int(toplevel_width)
        y = int(toplevel_height)    
     
        self.lbl_text_guia .place(x=x, y=y)

    def open_image_miniature(self, event):
        if self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial .grid_info() == {}:
            self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial .grid()
        else:
            self.frame_image_mobil_tutorial .grid_remove()
```

```py
#--- main ---

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    folder = sys.argv[1]
    print('if:', folder, len(folder))
else:
    folder = os.getcwd()  # c:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\proyecto

root = Tk()
root .geometry('300x300+300+300')
frm = TopCls(root, folder)
frm.pack()
root.mainloop()
```